# Extract session key from encrypted access token

Tags: facebook, access-token

How can I extract the session key from an encrypted access token? Can we extract the session key from signed_request?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can/should use PHP SDK to easily use GRAPH API

https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk